# Get the details but ignore user if exist another higher level

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table looks like

```
id  user_id  level

1     1        1
2     1        2
3     2        1
4     3        1
```

Here user id 1 exist in level 1 and level 2
Now when we count group by level then in counting we want ignore user_id  1 from level 1 cause it exist another group.  we want to consider only one group existing and higher group.

I have done only group count but cant understand how ignore counting.

My current query is

```
UserCertificate::with('user')
    ->where('level','1')
    ->distinct('level')
    ->orderBy('id','ASC')
    ->get();
```

My Query return  counting

```
id  user_id  level

1     1        1
3     2        1
4     3        1
```

But I want looks like

```
id  user_id  level

3     2        1
4     3        1
```

User Id 1 will be ignored cause it exist in level 2

Comment: i think its a good Question!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sub query`

```
select * from user
where user_id != (
select user_id from user where  level != 1
) and level = 1
group by user_id,level
```

in your code like this

```
UserCertificate::with('user')->where('level','1')->where('user_id != (select user_id from user where level != 1)')->group_by(array("user_id", "level"))->orderBy('id','ASC')->get();
```

Demo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd214e/30

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by join table itself by user_id like:

```
select UserCertificate.* 
from UserCertificate
left join UserCertificate UserCertificate2 on 
    UserCertificate.user_id = UserCertificate2.user_id and 
    UserCertificate.level < UserCertificate2.level
where UserCertificate.level = 1 and UserCertificate2.level is null
;
```

[Here it can be tested](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=7f74860e378deb99a0fd4e212214ad4d&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

**result**:

```
id    user_id    level
3     2          1
4     3          1
```